# Markers will not appear on Google Map

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I went around the site to see if there was any suggestions to try before asking this. Also have asked classmates. They tried the code and it works for them but for some reason it will not work on mine. My markers will not appear for some reason.

Manually it works but from the database it doesn't. DB2 database was used.

I do have a Google Maps API key and am using it.

This is the code I have for the display:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">
    <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script async defer
                        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykey&libraries=places&callback=init">
                </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var map;
        var marker;
//function 1         
        function init() {
                var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.6500, -121.9100); //center
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();         
                var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 9,
                center: center,
                }
                 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
                 $.post("schooljson.php",
                    {lat: "latitude", 
                    lng: "longitude",
                    loc: "location"},  
                    function(data){
                         loadSchools(data);
                 }, "json");

 // function 2
      function loadSchools(data)
      {
            for(var j in data){                                                    
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {
                        lng: data[j].lat, // sometimes these are reversed
                        lat: data[j].longitude,
                        map: map
                    }
                });
            marker.setMap(map);  
               // google.maps.event.addDomListener(marker, 'load', init);
                 /*ADD MARKER LISTENERS HERE*/
            }    
      }
 }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map" style="width: 70%; height: 500px;"></div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my PHP:

```php
<?php
//phpinfo();
//exit;

require 'connect.php';

try{
    $conn = db2_connect($database, $user, $pass);
}
catch( Exception $e ){
    echo "Exception: ". $e->getMessage();
}

if( $conn ){
    $sql ="select name1, name2, street, city, zip, county, db2gse.ST_X(loc), db2gse.ST_Y(loc), loc
from school";
    $stmt = db2_prepare($conn, $sql);

    if( $stmt)
    {
        $result = db2_execute($stmt);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No results";
    }
    while($row = db2_fetch_array($stmt))
    {
        $json[] = array(
            'name1' => $row[0],
            'name2' => $row[1],
            'street' => $row[2],
            'city' => $row[3],
            'zip' => $row[4],
            'county' => $row[5],
            'loc' => $row[8],
            'lat' => $row[6],
            'longitude' => $row[7]);
    }

    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $jsonstring = json_encode($json);
    echo $jsonstring;   

    db2_close($conn);
}
else{
    echo db2_conn_error()."<br>";
    echo db2_conn_errormsg()."<br>";
    echo "Connection failed.<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting a php error?

Comment: Post an answer on what happened so we can vote it up...

Comment: Oh no there's no php error.  Posted. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like some extension was installed on my Google Chrome I did not know about and uninstall it, so it's fixed now!